# libfm fm_standard_view_new SIGSEGV

Tags: c, gtk, linux

```
FmStandardView* objPreView=NULL; 
objPreView=fm_standard_view_new(FM_FV_LIST_VIEW, NULL, NULL);
```

На что получаю:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x2C
at 0x53A114E: fm_standard_view_set_mode (in /usr/lib/libfm-gtk3.so.4.0.0)
by 0x53A150F: fm_standard_view_new (in /usr/lib/libfm-gtk3.so.4.0.0)
by 0x402CD3: main (main.c:101)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ох. Я просто не инициализировал libfm. Извините, что тупил.